# FileWriter is throwing some FileNotFound Exception in java class

Tags: java, event-handling, fileoutputstream

This is the code for the Transaction class in my project The class is supposed to get the value from the user and to get the detail record/report of the patient in the file.txt but it seems to be not working properly and if the class is executed the "Amount Cannot Be 0 or Negative" dialog is thrown even if the conditions meet.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Transaction extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    Container container = getContentPane();
    String pname = "";
    int page = 0;
    String speciality = "";
    float amt = 0;
    int flag = 0;
    int rating = 0;
    String roomCategory = "";
    String treatment = "";

    String filename = "";
    String record = "";

    private final JLabel transactionDetailsLabel = new JLabel("Transaction Details");

    JLabel baseCostLabel = new JLabel("Base Amount :");
    JTextField baseCostTextField = new JTextField();

    JLabel taxLabel = new JLabel("Service Tax :");
    JLabel taxValueLabel = new JLabel("5%");

    JLabel gstTaxLabel = new JLabel("GST Tax :");
    JLabel gstValueTaxLabel = new JLabel("18%");

    JLabel totalAmt = new JLabel("Gross Payable Amt :");
    JLabel totalAmtLabel = new JLabel("");

    JButton generateBillButton = new JButton("Generate & Save Bill");
    JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");

    Transaction(String pname, int page, String pspeciality, int rating, String treatment, String roomCategory) {
        this.pname = pname;
        this.page = page;
        this.speciality = pspeciality;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.roomCategory = roomCategory;
        this.treatment = treatment;

        setLayoutManager();
        setLocationAndSize();
        addComponentsToContainer();
        addActionEvent();
    }

    public void setLayoutManager() {
        container.setLayout(null);
    }

    public void setLocationAndSize() {
        transactionDetailsLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 26));
        transactionDetailsLabel.setBounds(280, 30, 250, 70);

        baseCostLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 22));
        baseCostLabel.setBounds(164, 150, 200, 30);
        baseCostTextField.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 22));
        baseCostTextField.setBounds(464, 150, 200, 30);

        taxLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 22));
        taxLabel.setBounds(164, 200, 200, 30);
        taxValueLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 22));
        taxValueLabel.setBounds(464, 200, 200, 30);

        gstTaxLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 22));
        gstTaxLabel.setBounds(164, 250, 200, 30);
        gstValueTaxLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 22));
        gstValueTaxLabel.setBounds(464, 250, 200, 30);

        totalAmt.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 22));
        totalAmt.setBounds(164, 300, 200, 30);
        totalAmtLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 22));
        totalAmtLabel.setBounds(464, 300, 200, 30);
        totalAmtLabel.setVisible(false);

        generateBillButton.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        generateBillButton.setBounds(175, 350, 275, 30);

        clearButton.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        clearButton.setBounds(500, 350, 131, 30);

        this.setTitle("Transaction Page");
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setBounds(10, 10, 832, 551);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int w = this.getSize().width;
        int h = this.getSize().height;
        int x = (dim.width - w) / 2;
        int y = (dim.height - h) / 2;
        this.setLocation(x, y);
    }

    public void addComponentsToContainer() {
        container.add(baseCostLabel);
        container.add(baseCostTextField);
        container.add(taxLabel);
        container.add(taxValueLabel);
        container.add(gstTaxLabel);
        container.add(gstValueTaxLabel);
        container.add(totalAmt);
        container.add(totalAmtLabel);
        container.add(generateBillButton);
        container.add(clearButton);
        getContentPane().add(transactionDetailsLabel);
    }

    public void addActionEvent() {
        generateBillButton.addActionListener(this);
        clearButton.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public float getAmount() {
        try {
            amt = Integer.parseInt(baseCostTextField.getText().trim());
            if (amt > 0 && pname != "") {
                amt = (float) (amt + amt * 0.05 + amt * 0.18);
                String a = String.valueOf(amt);
                totalAmtLabel.setText(a);
                totalAmtLabel.setVisible(true);
                flag = 1;

                this.record = "Patient Name: " + pname + "\r\n" + "Patient Age: " + page + "\r\n" + "Speciality Treatment: "
                        + speciality + "\r\n" + "Treatment Category: " + treatment + "\r\n" + "Severitry Rating: " + rating + "\r\n" + "Room Category: " + roomCategory + "\r\n" + "Total Bill Amt: " + amt + "\r\n" + "----------------------------";

                this.filename = pname + "_" + page + ".txt";

            } else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Amount Cannot Be 0 or Negative");

        } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Check Details! Enter properly.");
        }
        return amt;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == generateBillButton) {
            this.getAmount();

            if (pname != "" && amt > 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Record Saved with amt: " + amt);
                new HomePage();
                dispose();
            }

            try {
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filename, true);
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(writer);

                bufferedWriter.write(record);
                bufferedWriter.newLine();
                bufferedWriter.close();

            } catch (IOException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        if (e.getSource() == clearButton) {
            baseCostTextField.setText("");
            totalAmtLabel.setText("");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Transaction add_transaction_frame = new Transaction("A", 58, "Dental", 7, "Fracture", "ICU");
    }
}
```

It keeps throwing FileNotFoundException

```
Accepted Entry
4
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:293)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:235)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:155)
    at java.base/java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:82)
    at Transaction.actionPerformed(Transaction.java:171)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6626)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3389)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:743)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Please Help me out here to understand excatly where and what mistake am I doing and what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace you posted has this at the top:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:293)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:235)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:155)
    at java.base/java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:82)
    at Transaction.actionPerformed(Transaction.java:171)
```

where that last line – `Transaction.actionPerformed` – is your code.

In your `actionPerformed()` method, you have this line:

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filename, true);
```

That member – `filename` – is declared at the top of your code as an empty string:

```
String filename = "";
```

And the only place you're setting `filename` to anything is in your `getAmount()` method, and only if this condition evaluates to true: `amt > 0 && pname != ""` (that's from the `if` statement).

I didn't look close enough at your code to answer which of these applies, but the reason you're seeing a `FileNotFoundException` is due to one of the following:

- if you're not calling `getAmount()`, then `filename` is `""` which won't work
- if you call `getAmount()`, but the `if` condition isn't true, you get the same empty value for `filename`
- if you call `getAmount()` *and* the condition is true, then you're going to set `filename` to: `pname + "_" + page + ".txt"` – I have no idea whether that results in a valid filename for your program to use